# Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet (PS ver. 5.x !!)

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

i believe the title is self explanatory. 
The install-module isn't working anymore. I had it running earlier, but after downloading NuGet through powershell the module doesn't work anymore at all, giving me the error message shown in the title.
I'm running on Windows 10, Powershell Ver.: 5.1.16299.15.

The question has been asked before, but on other threads the problem was the Powershell version, which isn't the case for me.

Comment: Does `Get-Command Install-Module -All` or `Get-Command -Module PowerShellGet` show any output?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The first command gives me the same result as just "install-module".. an error. The second command doesnt give me an output at all and just jumps to the next command line.

Comment: may be `Get-Module -Name PowerShellGet -ListAvailable` as well.

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV same problem. That command doesn't return any output.

Comment: can you check whether `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` has `PowerShellGet` folder

Comment: Yes, the folder is there. (ver 1.0.0.1)

Comment: It seems none of the commands from "PowershellGet" work. I wonder if there is a way to reinstall this.

Comment: Can you post the command you ran to download nuget?

Comment: @MikeTwc when i first tried "install-module" NuGet was downloaded automatically after approving a small "y/n"-prompt. it's since then that install-module completely broke.

Comment: What is the `ModuleVersion` in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PowerShellGet.psd1`

Comment: @PrasoonKarunanVits '1.0.0.1'

Comment: Does `$env:PSModulePath` output has `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` , ideally it should have, but...

Comment: D:\\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;D:\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules" ....this is the content of PSModulePath..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotcha! - From above discussions,

Did you change `$env:PSModulePath` ? Nuget installation would not change it. You can add `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` in the list and try.

```
$env:PSModulePath += ';C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'
```

Comment: Sir, you saved my day. You're solution worked perfectly!

Comment: NOTE: I have a very small C:/ drive, so I install all my software on D:/. Some programs like google chrome wouldn't let me choose the install drive, though, so i changed the registry entry for standard install locations. In theory a simple solution, since important software like .NET Framework goes to C:/ (Or whatever drive you have Windows on) anyways. BUT it seems that the installation of NuGet took this changed registry entry and caused some unexpected changes to "$env:PSModulePath", which tells Powershell where to look for Modules.. This is just a guess but very likely caused the trouble.